# New custom retention formula in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

How to create custom retention formula in SharePoint Online? There are lot of guides how to do it in on-prem environments, but none for online.. Is this a disabled legacy feature that I am seeing?

[image]